# Return Empty rows when Where clause does not match an entry in PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, null, where-clause

I'm running a simple `SELECT` statement on my PostgreSQL DB that looks like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE primary_key IN (a, b, c);
```

If `my_table` only has entries corresponding to the primary keys `a`, and `c`, then the query will only return two rows - one for `a` and all its data, and one for `c` and all its data.

I want the query to return an *empty row* (or a `NULL`/`nil` value) whenever there is no entry for the primary key in the table.
So I want the output of the above `SELECT` query to be [`a_data`, `nil`, `b_data`] instead of [`a_data`, `b_data`]. Is there a way to accomplish this?

More generally, if I have `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE primary_key IN (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)`, I want there to be `n` rows returned, where `x_data` is `NULL`/`nil` for every `x` that doesn't exist as a key in the DB.

Comment: Create a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) by `UNION` of all key values and then `LEFT JOIN` it with your table.

Comment: But that would still give me non-nil entries when I execute the above `SELECT` query on the joined table, right?

Answer (score 3):

Use a derived table and left join.  In Postgres, this looks like:

```
select t.primary_key, primary_key
from (values (a), (b), (c)) v(primary_key) left join
     my_table t
     using (primary_key);
```

Comment: running this on an interactive PostgreSQL DB session gives me the following error:
```
$ SELECT * FROM (VALUES (a), (b), (c)) v(primary_key) LEFT JOIN my_table t USING (primary_key);
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM (VALUES (a), (b), (c)) v(primary_key) L...
                                                              ^
```

Comment: @shubhamgoenka: Missing quotes. With string constants, make that `... VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c') ...` (Your original example has the same syntax error.)

Comment: @shubhamgoenka . . . Your question does not use single quotes on the values, so I did not include them here.  If they are literal string values, then use single quotes.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten an output that looks like this:
```
my_database=# SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c')) v(primary_key) LEFT JOIN my_table t USING (primary_key);
 primary_key 
--------------
 a
 b
 c
(3 rows)
```
my table only has one column (i.e., the primary key), so with this solution, I have no way of knowing whether the entries in the output came from the table or not. Is there a way to distinguish, from the output, what was originally in the table vs. what wasn't? Perhaps through a `null` value instead of `b` ?

Comment: @shubhamgoenka . . . If you select `primary_key`, you will always get a value.  If you select `t.primary_key` you will see if there is a match.